# Get all replies in SharePoint Sitefeed using REST api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to use RESTful services to return all replies in a SharePoint sitefeed. Currently, I am successfully using this code to retrieve the sitefeed's posts:

```
function getFeed(){
var feed;
var reply;
var rCounter;
$.ajax({
    url: "https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/<sitename>/_api/social.feed/actor(item=@v)/feed?@v=%27https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/<sitename>/newsfeed.aspx%27",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        // Returning the results
        myFeed = $(data);
        console.log(myFeed);
        for (i = 0; i < myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results.length; i++) {
             feed = (myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[i].RootPost.Text);
             console.log(myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[0].Actors.results[1].Name + ": " + feed);
                if (myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[i].Replies.results.length >0){
                    rCounter = myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[i].Replies.results.length;
                    for (j = 0; j < myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[i].Replies.results.length; j++) {
                        rCounter--;
                        reply = myFeed[0].d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[i].Replies.results[rCounter].Text;
                        console.log(reply);
                    }
                 }
            console.log("* * * * * * * * *");    
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("ERROR - SEE CODE");
    }
    });

}
```

However, this gives me the posts but with only the two latest replies. According to [this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn155789.aspx#bk_post), I need to use a POST method to get all replies and pass in the thread ID. So I made a new function:

```
function getPost(){
$.ajax({
    url: "https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/<sitename>/_api/social.feed/post(ID=ai)/?@ai='8.211b75cd6dc84fe4bc6c3e9f46971f51.97717348cd3048768103d55751dc0e2d.211b75cd6dc84fe4bc6c3e9f46971f51.819bde2276b948a8a120964289476489.17c08f26b90a4b659ff1fcfb0ede4025.5.5.1'",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        // Returning the results
        console.log($(data));
        },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("ERROR - SEE CODE");
    }
    });
}
```

When I run this new function, I get a 403 (FORBIDDEN) error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In every POST method you have to pass 'X-RequestDigest' header value.

Answer (score 1):

try passing headers like below.

function getPost(){

$.ajax({

```
url: "https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/<sitename>/_api/social.feed/post(ID=ai)/?@ai='8.211b75cd6dc84fe4bc6c3e9f46971f51.97717348cd3048768103d55751dc0e2d.211b75cd6dc84fe4bc6c3e9f46971f51.819bde2276b948a8a120964289476489.17c08f26b90a4b659ff1fcfb0ede4025.5.5.1'",
method: "POST",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
success: function (data) {
    // Returning the results
    console.log($(data));
    },
error: function (data) {
    console.log("ERROR - SEE CODE");
}
});
```

}